# Can Anyone give me proper navigation examples using zend_nevigation in zend 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am new to zend.
I have a three roles in my project.

1. Admin
2. manager
3. Employee

Each role has some similar and some different menus they can access..

Like :-

Admin Role :-

```
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|   Controller          | action                   | 
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|   Dashborad           | Index                    |
|   Manager             | Index, Add, edit, delete |
|   Employee            | Index, Add, edit, delete |
|   task                | Index, Add, edit, delete |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Manager Role :-

```
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|   Controller          | action                   | 
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|   mDashborad          | Index                    |
|   Employee            | Index, Add, edit, delete |
|   task                | Index, Add, edit, delete |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

Employee Role :-

```
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|   Controller          | action                   | 
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
|   uDashborad          | Index                    |
|   task                | Index, edit              |
+-----------------------+--------------------------+
```

now in the above role wise controller and action declared.

how can i declare role wise menu using zend_nevigation in zend 1.11

I want only idea to start this work in my project.

please help if you have any idea to how can it design my menu as role wise...

Answer (score 1):

I created a view helper to solve this issue. Here's some sample code.

```
class Zend_View_Helper_NavBar extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {

    public function NavBar($role) {
        $view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
            ->getParam('bootstrap')
            ->getResource('view');

    $menu = '<menu id="menu">
            <ul>';

    switch($role) {
        case ADMIN:
            $menu .= '<li';
            if($view->onHomePage) $menu .= ' class="selected"';
            $menu .= '><a href="/">Home</a></li><li';
            (continue adding links)
            break;
        case MANAGER:
            $menu .= '<li';
            if($view->onHomePage) $menu .= ' class="selected"';
            $menu .= '><a href="/">Home</a></li><li';
            (continue adding links)
            break;
        case EMPLOYEE:
        default:
            $menu .= '<li';
            if($view->onHomePage) $menu .= ' class="selected"';
            $menu .= '><a href="/">Home</a></li><li';
            (continue adding links)
            break;
    } 

    return $menu;

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks liz but i want to define menu using Zend_Navigation.